# Unable to resolve the error while using Java 8 mapping and maxBy operations

Tags: java-8

This is what I am trying to achieve

Group the Blog posts by type. Within each Type, trying to produce the names of the titles and reduce by maximum length.

and this is the below logic I am trying to use.

```
    BlogPost b1 = new BlogPost("Story behind Harry Potter", "J.K.Rowling", BlogPostType.FICTION, 100);
    BlogPost b2=  new BlogPost("Java 8 Tutorial", "Vinay",  BlogPostType.TECH, 10);
    BlogPost b3 = new BlogPost("Python Tutorial", "Jim", BlogPostType.TECH, 20);
    BlogPost b4 = new BlogPost("Mission Impossible", "Kim", BlogPostType.REVIEW, 40);
    BlogPost b5 = new BlogPost("Bomb Blast", "Kenny", BlogPostType.NEWS, 200);
    BlogPost b6 = new BlogPost("President Visits", "Laura", BlogPostType.NEWS, 400);
    List<BlogPost> posts = Arrays.asList(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6);

Map<String, Optional<String>> postsPer = posts.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(BlogPost::getType, 
Collectors.mapping(BlogPost::getTitles, 
Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(String::length)))));
```

And I am unable to figure out how to resolve this. The IDE points the below line in red

```
 mapping(BlogPost::getTitles
```

and the below mentioned errors/markers show up which I am unable to resolve.

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The method mapping(Function<? super T,? extends U>, Collector<? super U,A,R>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments (BlogPost::getTitles, Collector<String,capture#60-
 of ?,Optional<String>>)
- The type BlogPost does not define getTitles(T) that is applicable here
```

Below are the classes

```
package com.main.java8.streams.groupingby;
class BlogPost {
String title;
String author;
BlogPostType type;
int likes;
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}
public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}
/*@Override
public String toString() {
    return "BlogPost [title=" + title + ", author=" + author + ", type=" + type + ", likes=" + likes + "]";
}*/
public BlogPostType getType() {
    return type;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "BlogPost [title=" + title + "]";
}
public void setType(BlogPostType type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public int getLikes() {
    return likes;
}
public void setLikes(int likes) {
    this.likes = likes;
}
public BlogPost(String title, String author, BlogPostType type, int likes) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.type = type;
    this.likes = likes;
}

}



package com.main.java8.streams.groupingby;
enum BlogPostType {
NEWS,
REVIEW,
GUIDE,
FICTION,
TECH
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what's going on here, but if I had to guess I would say that `BlogPost::getTitles` is not of type `Function<? super T,? extends U>`

Answer (score 4):

`BlogPost::getTitles` is highlighted in red because it's a typo, your method is called `getTitle`.  Compiler's message "The type BlogPost does not define getTitles(T) that is applicable here" tells you exactly what's wrong.

Additionally, the type of `postsPer` should be `Map<BlogPostType...` rather than `Map<String, ...`

With that,

```
Map<BlogPostType, Optional<String>> postsPer = posts.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(BlogPost::getType,
            Collectors.mapping(BlogPost::getTitle,
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(String::length)))));
```

Should compile fine.

On another note, you can avoid the `Optional` and more straightforwardly express this with a 3-argument `toMap` collector:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

Map<BlogPostType, String> postsPer = posts.stream()
        .collect(toMap(
                BlogPost::getType, 
                BlogPost::getTitle, 
                BinaryOperator.maxBy(comparing(String::length))
        ));
```

Comment: I feel so embarrassed. I was staring at the code for 45 min thinking what was wrong, when all the while it was Typo. Thank you very much for pointing out patiently. Thank you @Misha.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used `Entity/DTO::propertyName`,
however is should be `Entity/DTO::getProertyName`.